# Transceiver IC SN74LV245A at different voltage levels pull up resistor require for current improvement

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, high-speed, transceiver

I've gone through  [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scls382o/scls382o.pdf) of IC Page number 12 Figure 5 shows typical application of IC which is 5 to 3.3V compatibility.

In my design My sensor Output is 1.5V to  2.2V so we're planning to have 2V supply. Now for latching 8mA current from IC with input of 1.5V I want my Output to be 2V.

What I could understand from Recommended Operating Conditions from Page 6 Section 7.3 is High-level output current at 2V is -50uA please guide us whether having pullup resistor over here will work or is there any alternative part available or this.

Thanks

Comment: What pullup resistor would your load require to operate at 2 volts? What is the maximum voltage permitted at the load in a zero input state? That resistance and the minimum voltage would give the pulldown current requirement, and the voltage combined with the current is what you need to check for in the sink current section.

Comment: Maximum voltage at zero input stage is 0.6V and planning to use 5k pull up at 2 volts